# SQL: Records are deleted, the key is a sequence number. At least 2 others tables store refs to the sequence number, but not as a key. Solution?

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm working in a system where my table (let's call it MAIN_TAB) has many records, and the key is a sequence number.

There are at least (likely more) 3 other tables that have an attribute storing a reference to MAIN_TAB's sequence.

**In some these tables, it's not a foreign key, merely a reference for user eyeballs.**
**In another table, it IS part of the key.**

In either case, these refs are also in business logic to connect tables to individual records in MAIN_TAB.

*Here's where things go sour:*

There's a process that regenerates the data in MAIN_TAB by removing all existing records and recreating them, and consequently all the sequence numbers are new.
This means the 2 other tables that stored a reference to MAIN_TAB's sequence now refer to sequence numbers that no longer exist.

Either I'll need to find every table that stored a reference to MAIN_TAB's sequence and update them all to the new sequence numbers (I'm not a fan of this approach). This will involve updating at least one foreign key in one table, and updating references in others...

or,

During the transaction that regenerates MAIN_TAB, save a list of its existing sequence numbers (there are enough attributes to uniquely identify each record without using the sequence) and overwrite the sequence numbers using this list. I'm even less a fan of this approach because it's a key update.

What would you do, stack overflowers?

Comment: I personally would rather look at fixing the actual issue that managing the symptoms - i.e. why are all the rows in MAIN_TAB being removed and recreated? Instead, it sounds like some sort of staging table is required that can then be loaded into and then compared to MAIN_TAB, and then changes to MAIN_TAB can be applied on just the affected rows, meaning you're not having to drop and reload so much data, not to mention changing the key values of each row every time. Oh, and add in those missing foreign keys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.